# Problem with entity mapping with composite key. Spring JPA

Tags: java

Good morning guys, I looked for some question related to this but I really couldn't find it.

I am developing a Rest API for a financial transaction system where I have 3 entities, all of them with PK composed with table id and user id:

Finances: Financial transactions (keys: financeId, userId)
Payment: Paymenst (keys: paymentId, userId)
Category: Categories of transactions (keys: categoryId, userId)

The CRUD of Payment and Category have already worked normally, but in Finance I was only able to make Gets work, it is looking for all fields correctly, however in the insert Hibernate is ignoring the attributes that link Finance to Payment and Category, and I can't find the reason.

The entity Finance

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "financeiros")
public class Finance{

    @EmbeddedId
    private FinanceId financeId;

    @Column(name = "dtcompra")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date buyDate;

    @Column(name = "dtbaixa")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date payDate;

    @Column(name = "dtvencimento")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dueDate;

    @Column(name = "recdesp")
    private Integer recdesp;

    @Column(name = "valor")
    private Float value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "codnat", referencedColumnName = "codnat",insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "codpgmt", referencedColumnName = "codpgmt", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Payment payment;

    @Column(name = "observacao")
    private String note;

    @Column(name = "dtlancamento")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateIncluded;

    @Column(name = "dtmodificacao")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateModified;
```

}

The class of key financeId

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class FinanceId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "codfin")
    private Integer financeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private UserIdFilter userIdFilter;

    public FinanceId() {
    }

    public FinanceId(Integer financeId, Integer userId) {
        this.financeId = financeId;
        this.userIdFilter = new UserIdFilter(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        FinanceId financeId1 = (FinanceId) o;
        return Objects.equals(financeId, financeId1.financeId) &&
                Objects.equals(userIdFilter, financeId1.userIdFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(financeId, userIdFilter);
    }

}
```

When I'm going to POST a FINANCE object to persist in the bank, I build the object like this:

```
public Finance insertNewFinance(FinanceDto financeDto, Integer userId) {
Finance finance = new Finance();
finance.setBuyDate(financeDto.getBuyDate());
finance.setDueDate(financeDto.getDueDate());
finance.setCategory(categoryService.getByCategoryId(financeDto.getCategoryId(), userId));
finance.setPayment(paymentService.getByPaymentId(financeDto.getPaymentId(), userId));
finance.setDateIncluded(new Date());
finance.setDateModified(new Date());
finance.setNote(financeDto.getNote());
finance.setRecdesp(financeDto.getRecdesp());
finance.setValue(financeDto.getValue());

FinanceId financeId = new FinanceId(financeRepository.findNextId(userId), userId);
finance.setFinanceId(financeId);

return financeRepository.save(finance);
}
```

Here is the problem, in the executed SQL log the following Insert appears:

```
Hibernate: insert into `financeiros` (`dtcompra`, `dtlancamento`, `dtmodificacao`, `dtvencimento`, `observacao`, `dtbaixa`, `recdesp`, `valor`, `codfin`, `user_id`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The link fields do not appear (codpgmt, codnat) in the insert

I already tried to remove the attribute "insertable = false" but the spring returned me: user_id (should be mapped with insert = "false" update = "false")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cascade = CascadeType.ALL or CascadeType.PERSIST in @OneToMany / @ManyToOne.